# Trying to prove that $\mathbb{G}_m^2$ is isomorphic to $D_2$ (algebraic groups)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, affine-schemes

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. 
I have learned that $\mathbb{G}_m^2$ is isomorphic as algebraic groups to $D_2$ (invertible diagonal matrix $2$ by $2$), but I am struggling to provide all the details due to perhaps my lack of understanding of some basic materials. I have no doubt that this is indeed the case, but I would appreciate if someone could provide me with a more detailed explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isomorphism just sends $(x,y)$ to the $2$ by $2$ matrix that has $x,y$ on the diagonal and $0$ in the other corners.

This is clearly natural in the $k$-algebra $R$, and is clearly a pointwise isomorphism, hence a natural isomorphism.

You can also see it in terms of representing algebras : both $\mathbb{G}_m^2$ and $D_2$ are representable by $k$-algebras and as such are isomorphic if and only if their representing algebras are isomorphic.

$\mathbb{G}_m^2$ is represented by $k[X,X^{-1},Y,Y^{-1}]$ while $D_2$ is represented by $k[X,Y,Z,T, (XT-YZ)^{-1}]/(Y,Z)\simeq k[X,T,(XT)^{-1}] \simeq k[X,T,X^{-1},T^{-1}]$ and therefore they are isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Couple questions 1)  What do you mean by: this is "natural" in the $k$-algabra? 2) What is the meaning of representable? (Is this just taking the coordinate ring?)

Comment: I think both questions can be answered by the fact that $\mathbb{G}_m^2, D_2$ are functors, and if you don't get that it means I probably misunderstood your question (because schemes can be seen either as geometric objects or as functors, and I used their functorial version here)

Comment: Ah i see ok, actually I get the second part of my question now. But what does "natural" in the $k$-algabra mean and "natural" isomorphism mean (as in is natural here mathematical meaning or no-math meaning?)

Comment: Well natural as in a natural transformation; a morphism of functors